# Error activating virtualenv with docker ENTRYPOINT script

Tags: python, django, docker, virtualenv, alpine-linux

I am trying to build a simple Django Docker container with virtualenv setup on ***Windows 10***. The image itself is build successfully, however when I attempt to start the containers with the entrypoint script, I am getting a weird error that my virtualenv files are not found.

Note that the container was working perfectly fine before I decided to add the virtualenv  section (as per my **TODO** note in the **Dockerfile**). The container was **UP** and running.

Can anyone share their thoughts as to why this is happening? Note this is my first alpine image.

**PS**. I am using **PyCharm** as my IDE and I have changed all line separators to be `LF`

```
D:\Code\Projects\Test_virtualenv_Dockerfiles>docker-compose ps
   Name                  Command               State    Ports
-------------------------------------------------------------
django_test   /venv-entrypoint.sh sh -c  ...   Exit 2
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.2'

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Deploy/Django/Dockerfile
    image: django_test
    container_name: django_test
    volumes:
      - .:/app_server
    ports:
      - "9000:8000"
    tty: true
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

MAINTAINER cBeTyLkaTa

# Setup environment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    RUN_USER=www-data \
    ENV_DIR=/app_server \
    VIRTUALENV_DIR=/app_server/venv \
    BIN_DIR=/app_server/venv/bin \
    HOME_DIR=/var/www

# Create new run user
RUN adduser -D $RUN_USER

# Setup work directory
RUN mkdir $ENV_DIR $HOME_DIR
WORKDIR $ENV_DIR


# Install packages
# NB. Adding bash as Alpine images do not have installed by default (otherwise use `ash` to login)
RUN apk add --no-cache --update bash
RUN apk update && \
    apk add make \
    curl \
    vim \
    git

# Setup virtual environment and install requirements/dependencies
COPY requirements.txt $ENV_DIR/requirements.txt
RUN pip install virtualenv
RUN virtualenv -p python venv
RUN $BIN_DIR/pip install -r $ENV_DIR/requirements.txt

COPY . $ENV_DIR

EXPOSE 9000

# TODO add entrypoint to activate the virtual environment
COPY Deploy/Django/venv-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod a+x /venv-entrypoint.sh

# Change file permission for the new run user and switch to that user
#RUN chown -R $RUN_USER:$RUN_USER $ENV_DIR $HOME_DIR /venv-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/venv-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**venv-entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
source /app_server/venv/bin/activate
exec "$@"
```

**Build output**

```
Building web
Step 1/17 : FROM python:3.8-alpine
 ---> 6c32e2504283
Step 2/17 : MAINTAINER cBeTyLkaTa
 ---> Running in 15a8c54f6108
Removing intermediate container 15a8c54f6108
 ---> 193086010346
Step 3/17 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1     RUN_USER=www-data     ENV_DIR=/app_server     VIRTUALENV_DIR=/app_server/venv     BIN_DIR=/app_server/venv/bin     HOME_DIR=/var/www
 ---> Running in 58d3674079a0
Removing intermediate container 58d3674079a0
 ---> e6d90a27efe8
Step 4/17 : RUN adduser -D $RUN_USER
 ---> Running in d126a2f85982
Removing intermediate container d126a2f85982
 ---> 934ff481f5c8
Step 5/17 : RUN mkdir $ENV_DIR $HOME_DIR
 ---> Running in 896b80dcd473
Removing intermediate container 896b80dcd473
 ---> 529d46ca0266
Step 6/17 : WORKDIR $ENV_DIR
 ---> Running in a452c441afd4
Removing intermediate container a452c441afd4
 ---> d1d30ed270b0
Step 7/17 : RUN apk add --no-cache --update bash
 ---> Running in d71f7a25654f
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/1) Installing bash (5.0.11-r1)
Executing bash-5.0.11-r1.post-install
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r9.trigger
OK: 12 MiB in 35 packages
Removing intermediate container d71f7a25654f
 ---> c26f3c97b47d
Step 8/17 : RUN apk update &&     apk add make     curl     vim     git
 ---> Running in a8fe50461a39
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.11.6-22-g595722b8fb [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main]
v3.11.6-26-ga2d911e64f [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community]
OK: 11273 distinct packages available
(1/9) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.40.0-r0)
(2/9) Installing libcurl (7.67.0-r0)
(3/9) Installing curl (7.67.0-r0)
(4/9) Installing pcre2 (10.34-r1)
(5/9) Installing git (2.24.3-r0)
(6/9) Installing make (4.2.1-r2)
(7/9) Installing xxd (8.2.0-r0)
(8/9) Installing lua5.3-libs (5.3.5-r2)
(9/9) Installing vim (8.2.0-r0)
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r9.trigger
OK: 57 MiB in 44 packages
Removing intermediate container a8fe50461a39
 ---> dfec727547a6
Step 9/17 : COPY requirements.txt $ENV_DIR/requirements.txt
 ---> 8d51b6f66a53
Step 10/17 : RUN pip install virtualenv
 ---> Running in ce6cad56b303
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-20.0.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.7 MB)
Collecting six<2,>=1.9.0
  Downloading six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting appdirs<2,>=1.4.3
  Downloading appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting filelock<4,>=3.0.0
  Downloading filelock-3.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting distlib<1,>=0.3.0
  Downloading distlib-0.3.0.zip (571 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: distlib
  Building wheel for distlib (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for distlib (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for distlib: filename=distlib-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl size=340427 sha256=dc12892f48f7abbfcda57326432bf3d45baec7ad7c2f938780ec17362def0e8a
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/eb/4e/d2/a903d4184fb49e4ac06474d65715b129aee13d69f7d227e78e
Successfully built distlib
Installing collected packages: six, appdirs, filelock, distlib, virtualenv
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.3 distlib-0.3.0 filelock-3.0.12 six-1.14.0 virtualenv-20.0.20
Removing intermediate container ce6cad56b303
 ---> 99acb4562180
Step 11/17 : RUN virtualenv -p python venv
 ---> Running in 7896c112b9a5
created virtual environment CPython3.8.2.final.0-64 in 333ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/app_server/venv, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/root/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
Removing intermediate container 7896c112b9a5
 ---> ad3985329fd3
Step 12/17 : RUN $BIN_DIR/pip install -r $ENV_DIR/requirements.txt
 ---> Running in d6ac22e791e3
Collecting Django<3.0,>=2.0
  Downloading Django-2.2.12-py3-none-any.whl (7.5 MB)
Collecting sqlparse
  Downloading sqlparse-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting pytz
  Downloading pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Installing collected packages: sqlparse, pytz, Django
Successfully installed Django-2.2.12 pytz-2020.1 sqlparse-0.3.1
Removing intermediate container d6ac22e791e3
 ---> a69a36022d5b
Step 13/17 : COPY . $ENV_DIR
 ---> 2b8ab97814c8
Step 14/17 : EXPOSE 9000
 ---> Running in b54e93640150
Removing intermediate container b54e93640150
 ---> bec8bf51db4d
Step 15/17 : COPY Deploy/Django/venv-entrypoint.sh /
 ---> 298bac000732
Step 16/17 : RUN chmod a+x /venv-entrypoint.sh
 ---> Running in c51d2666deea
Removing intermediate container c51d2666deea
 ---> 9d1a03413c05
Step 17/17 : ENTRYPOINT ["/venv-entrypoint.sh"]
 ---> Running in f5cad5c0151a
Removing intermediate container f5cad5c0151a
 ---> d755701b46d9
Successfully built d755701b46d9
Successfully tagged django_test:latest
```

**docker logs**

```
Attaching to django_test
django_test | /venv-entrypoint.sh: source: line 2: can't open '/app_server/venv/bin/activate': No such file or directory
```

Container debug:

```
docker run -it django_test bash
.
.
(venv) /app_server # ls -l
total 28
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 May  1 11:15 Deploy
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           819 May  5 14:48 README.md.txt
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 May  3 16:35 db.sqlite3
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1097 May  5 15:50 docker-compose.yml
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           626 May  3 16:35 manage.py
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 May  3 16:35 mysite
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            16 May  3 15:52 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May  5 15:51 venv
(venv) /app_server # ls -l venv/bin/activate
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2205 May  5 15:51 venv/bin/activate
(venv) /app_server # ls -la /app_server/venv/bin/
total 88
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May  5 15:51 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May  5 15:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May  5 15:51 __pycache__
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2205 May  5 15:51 activate
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1424 May  5 15:51 activate.csh
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3055 May  5 15:51 activate.fish
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1751 May  5 15:51 activate.ps1
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1146 May  5 15:51 activate.xsh
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1199 May  5 15:51 activate_this.py
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           274 May  5 15:51 django-admin
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           136 May  5 15:51 django-admin.py
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           241 May  5 15:51 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           241 May  5 15:51 easy_install-3.8
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           241 May  5 15:51 easy_install3
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           232 May  5 15:51 pip
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           232 May  5 15:51 pip-3.8
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           232 May  5 15:51 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           232 May  5 15:51 pip3.8
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 May  5 15:51 python -> /usr/local/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             6 May  5 15:51 python3 -> python
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             6 May  5 15:51 python3.8 -> python
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           227 May  5 15:51 sqlformat
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           219 May  5 15:51 wheel
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           219 May  5 15:51 wheel-3.8
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           219 May  5 15:51 wheel3
(venv) /app_server # pip -V
pip 20.1 from /app_server/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
(venv) /app_server # which pip
/app_server/venv/bin/pip
(venv) /app_server # which python
/app_server/venv/bin/python
(venv) /app_server/venv/bin $ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
Django     2.2.12
pip        20.1
pytz       2020.1
setuptools 46.1.3
sqlparse   0.3.1
wheel      0.34.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your compose config, it's overriding `/app_server` with the directory from the host. Just delete the volumes from docker compose setup.

(As an aside, I recommend against using Alpine, it'll often result in slow Docker builds: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.This actually fixed the issue. However the question remains how will changes made on the host, reflect in the docker container without bringing down the running containers?

Comment: Probably want a volume mounting `./yourpackage` into `/app_server/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yourpackage` in compose.

Answer (score 0):

You don't generally need a virtual environment in a Docker image.  The image itself is isolated from the host system, and even if you install packages into the "system" Python, it will be separated from any other Python installation on the same host.

That lets you have a much simpler Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM python:3.8-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
# But don't set environment variables for container paths

# Are bash/curl/make/vim/git actually needed to run the application?
# Or as part of a `pip install` sequence?  Include only if required

WORKDIR /var/www
# Creates the directory for you

# Install Python dependencies into the "system" Python
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Install the rest of the application
COPY . ./

# Runtime metadata
RUN adduser -D www-data
USER www-data
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Now that your code, a standard `CMD`, and so on are built into the Dockerfile, you can also trim down the `docker-compose.yml` a little bit

```yaml
version: '3.2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Deploy/Django/Dockerfile
    image: django_test
    ports:
      - "9000:8000"
    # do not need container_name:, volumes:, tty:, command:
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. As I said in my post, things used to work just fine before I added the virtualenv in my build. This was more a question out of curiosity, why the virtualenv do not seem to exist in the container?

Comment: Because `volumes:` are hiding everything the Dockerfile does and replacing it with content from the host.  In this case since the virtual environment you're installing is inside the application tree, the `volumes:` hide that too, and at the point the container runs the virtual environment doesn't exist any more.

Comment: Very good point! After a quick re-structuring, all works as expected along with the `volumes:` enabled. Thanks!